# GzipStream file block compression

Tags: c#, .net

When I use the same GZipStream to compress file blocks in loop the result file compress successfully:

```
public static void Compress1(string fi)
        {
            using (FileStream inFile = File.Open(fi,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read))
            {

                using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi + ".gz"))
                {
                    using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile,
                            CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[6315120];
                        int numRead;
                        while ((numRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I compress file blocks separately in different streams the result file corrupts:

```
public static void Compress2(string fi, int offset)
    {
        using (FileStream inFile = File.Open(fi,FileMode.Open))
        { 
            using (FileStream outFile = File.OpenOrCreate(fi + ".gz"))
                {
                    using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile,
                            CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        // Copy the source file into the compression stream.
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[6315120];
                        int numRead=-1;
                        inFile.Seek(offset,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        numRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

In these examples I have a file with size = 12630240. And devide it into 2 blocks, size of each block = 6315120 (buffer size). So, the first block compress correctly in both methods, but the second block in second method compress different from the first method. What I missed?

Comment: In the second method which number you pass for upset?

Comment: i don't think you can divide the same file in different compress usings as some header are needed for the result to be valid.
EDIT:you can but the result must be to different gz files.

Comment: >In the second method which number you pass for upset?
first call -0, second call - 6315120

Comment: which header should I add?

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is you are creating to different files as each GZipStream has its one headers
by dividing what you are doing is creating to different GZ files and if you write the two to the same file it is a corrupt file.

Comment: @Mishgun_ - maybe adding what you're trying to achieve in the end ?